# Did arcade monitors have same pixel aspect ratio as TV sets?

Tags: hardware, display, arcade, ntsc

It is well known that when emulating classic games on modern displays, you need to be careful not to distort the aspect ratio. Generally speaking, CRT screens were 4:3, and specific pixel aspect ratios of many classic arcade games, consoles and computers are given [here](http://pineight.com/mw/index.php?title=Dot_clock_rates).

Of course, title safe area was a concern, particularly for home computers that had to work on many different models of TV sets. It's hard to say exactly what was the title safe area for NTSC TV, but the Commodore 64 is generally accepted as having come pretty close to it. From the above table, 320 pixels / 8.19 MHz = 39 microseconds, which sounds in the right ballpark.

NES: 256 pixels / 5.37 MHz = 47.6 microseconds. That is significantly past the title safe area and into overscan, but that's fine, that was a feature for a dedicated console; it matches one's memory of playing Super Mario Brothers, where objects would scroll onto the right of the screen without any visible border.

Missile Command: 256 pixels / 5 MHz = 51.2 microseconds. Hmm. That is even considerably further into overscan. Resources are being wasted generating pixels the player will never see...

... unless. That's an arcade machine. It came with its own screen. Sure, TV picture tube minus the tuner, 4:3 overall aspect ratio. But maybe they could have tweaked the display electronics to shrink the horizontal scan, so more of that 51.2 microsecond active scan line is visible.

But in that case, the calculated pixel aspect ratio of 27:22 would be no longer valid. And in general, it would be harder to figure out exactly what was the pixel aspect ratio of arcade machines. Calculating it from the pixel clock in the same way as for home computers and consoles would no longer give quite the correct results.

Is the above conjecture correct? Or did arcade machines actually use the same parameters as TV sets, and did Missile Command just accept some extra wasted pixels?

Comment: Key quotation from cited article: "Some coin-operated machines use a different active scanline period, and the arcade operator is expected to adjust the monitor's picture size to match a test pattern displayed in a particular game's service mode. "

Answer (score 37, accepted):

CRTs don't have pixels, they don't work that way. Also, arcade monitors expose all the picture controls at the back so it is possible to adjust them quite extensively. Operators would have made sure that the picture was the right shape and in focus near the edges.

Since the controls are all analogue and no-one bothered to measure the display geometry the aspect ratio was just close to 4:3, basically whatever looked good to whoever set it up.

The picture controls adjust the width of the beam scanning area, for example, so the pixel clock is irrelevant. The owner just turns the knob until the picture covers most of the screen. Games were designed with this in mind and the horizontal resolution was just that - resolution, not an attempt to create a particular aspect ratio.

with thanks to Tommy, here is an image from an actual CRT. In the upper right there is a zoomed in area from Sonic's foot, which shows some of the vertical bars that people often assume are pixels are in fact not evenly lit. The tops and bottoms of some of them are at different brightness levels.

[image]

The bars you can see are actually the shadow mask, and are unrelated to pixels. They define the maximum horizontal resolution that the CRT is capable of resolving, but even then the relationship is not 1:1.

Comment: Drats, I should have waited instead of writing many words. Good short version here. Except, of course are games created with a certain ratio in mind - the ship of defender must be a sleak fighter, not a bumble bee. But you are right, that these ratios are more of a guideline than the strict laws a CAD application will prefer.

Comment: "CRTs don't have pixels, they don't work that way. " What does that mean? The screen, at least on color CRTs, is separated into discrete regions.

Comment: @Acccumulation see https://youtu.be/Ea6tw-gulnQ but basically what you see on the TV is the result how it produces colour via different coloured phosphors and masking, not pixels.

Comment: @Acccumulation The red, green, blue phosphors, the discrete regions, on a colour CRT don't have any correspondence to the pixels being generated by the arcade machine's video circuitry, and it's these pixels that the original poster is talking about.

Comment: @Acccumulation: A CRT may have 480 horizontal lines making up the vertical resolution, but each of those lines has theoretically infinite horizontal resolution because the signal is analog.  However in practice the horizontal resolution is limited by the [TVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television_lines), which could reasonably  be called pixels.

Comment: @user I'm really unclear as to what the point of that is. My best guess is that each discrete region can contain detail (different parts of the region can have different brightnesses), as opposed to a pixel having to have the same brightness throughout the region. Is that what you and/or TC is saying?

Comment: @Acccumulation the "regions" are just holes in the shadow mask. That video explains it better than I can here, but they are not pixels and don't have to be uniformly lit. The beam intensity is analogue and the limit on resolution is more to do with the limitations of the electronics than the "regions", which are just holes in the shadow mask. There is no correlation at all between them and pixels though, unlike an LCD monitor.

Comment: @Acccumulation : Why do you think an entire phosphor lights up when some part of it is illuminated by the electron beam?  A monochrome CRT is not a one pixel device.  Full screen width horizontal phosphor striped CRTs were [patented](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6479937), but I don't know of a commercially successful one.

Comment: If it helps, see https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-swPay7tztq4/XJMFpkj3h0I/AAAAAAAABaU/nC2zH89zTOkBT0GJ7Sh1WZo-AxaL4KRIgCLcBGAs/s1600/IMG_2697.jpg for a shadow mask in action. In particular, zoom to 1:1 scale and check out e.g. the bottom of Sonic's shoes. You'll notice that the hard black line goes through the middle of many of the individual colour pools, demonstrating that they're not pixels. I took that picture myself, on a real CRT, so feel free to crop and/or embed in the answer if you think it's helpful.

Answer (score 14):

> Did arcade monitors have same pixel aspect ratio as TV sets?

Short answer: **No, not necessarily.**

---

Long Answer:

1. To start with, 'Title Safe Area' is an idea to define the **parts of *one* transmission to be displayed even if *any* of the many receivers is maladjusted**. It's nothing inherent to the TV signal or its definition, it's a safeguard against less than correct receivers.
2. Next, Pixel ratio is, even on a TV, complete arbitrary. TV sets a frame timing, but not a pixel one. The number frames per second and number of lines within a frame is defined by the respective standard, but that's it.
3. The number of pixels per line is, even on TV, infinite. Of course, as  they get defined 'tighter', as more restrictions due transmission and electronics appear. It's up to the application what restrictions are acceptable or not. In general, colour resolution on TV is less than luminescence resolution.
4. When it comes to the tube, none of these standards set any numbers. While they are made to fit certain standards, a CRT offers complete freedom, not only for pixels per line (as in TV) but also for number of lines per frame and frames per second - as long as it's within the CRTs abilities.
5. Parameters are set here mostly by screen mask (for colour games) resolution, phosphor used and electronics used for deflection.

As a result, even by using standard CRTs and average electronics resolution and pixel ratio can diverge quite from what a TV supports - and in both cases **Pixel resolution is arbitrary due the fact that signals are analogue** and not bound to any standard.

Pixel ratio in video games is thus defined by the generating computer system video circuit (assuming a correct alignment of the installed game/CRT). If a game (hardware) developer chooses a format of 512 lines by 1024, then that it is. Depending on the arcade cabinet setup (screen covers, etc), this may end up in any arbitrary ratio, not just 2:1 or 8:3. Being freed from TV specs is a great thing, isn't it :))

Comment: I wouldn't say that the pixels per line is infinite - more that while there is a limit of the amount of detail that can be discerned on any TV, framing it in terms of pixels is meaningless for analogue TV standards. While you can sometimes make approximate comparisons with digital resolutions in terms of how accurately you can describe detail, these are just that - approximate comparisons. Exactly how accurate they are will depend on the thing you're displaying.

Comment: @Muzer Well, that's the 'restrictions apply. If a TV can do like 200 lines (thats 400 pixel) wit the full dynamic of black to white, it can do 800 pixel with the restriction that each neighboring pixel may not differ by more than 50% luminosity and so on - and if that reminds anyone of the Amiga, yes, it's much like the restriction of its (in)famous HAM mode regarding colour change.

Comment: Per Nyquist's sampling theorem, the number of "pixels" in a fragment of a baseband analog signal is its duration times twice its highest frequency. For NTSC composite video, usable luma bandwidth is 3 MHz (with chroma at 3.0-4.2), but 240p/480i component (such as arcade RGB) can hit 8 MHz.

Comment: @DamianYerrick Nop, that's the minimum sampling frequency needed to sample such a signal. Not related to pixel or alike.

Comment: "luminance" is the normal word for the intensity/brightness part of the signal (as opposed to chrominance), not "luminescence".  The dictionary definitions are "the intensity of light emitted..." vs. "the emission of light by a substance that has not been heated".  So luminescence just describes the fact that light is being emitted at all because electrons are hitting phosphors (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathodoluminescence), not specifically the intensity.

Answer (score 8):

*Asteroids* is an example of an arcade cabinet that didn’t even use raster graphics, but vector graphics.  *Battlezone* and *Lunar Lander* were others.

They used similar technology to the Tektronix 4000-series terminals of the ’70s, or the IBM 2250:  A cathode ray fired into the back of a glass screen coated with phosphors, like in an old-fashioned black-and-white TV, but instead of moving across each row of the stream in a regular pattern and switching on and off, it instead followed a more complex path to draw geometric line art.

Comment: Interesting - but you should expand this to explain what the effective resolution in lp/mm was - that's about as close to "pixel ratio" as you can get with an analog display

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You might enjoy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkHjG759ABY

Comment: [Battlezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlezone_(1980_video_game)) and [Lunar Lander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Lander_(1979_video_game)) were also vector graphics games. The [IBM 2250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_2250) and the [CDC 6600 console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_6600) were vector graphics terminals.

Comment: @Davislor  Cool -- but I was distracted by the 1-second clip, badly out of focus, of a pingame.  Now I'll waste hours on  ipdb.org to figure out what game that was.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - there is no "effective resolution" of such a display, as the monitor itself is *analog* in both axis, much as a raster CRT is analog in the horizontal one.  The calculations and graphics driver hardware would have a resolution, but not the monitor.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Although you could talk about the frequency at which the hardware could move the beam, and therefore the shortest line segment it can draw.

Comment: No, because the slew rate isn't fixed by the monitor either, though there is some interaction with brightness.  Also note that exceeding the bandwidth means rounding the paths, not eliminating them entirely. Analog means analog.  And unlike a raster machine the HV supply is independent of the deflection circuits.

Comment: @ChrisStratton But to put it another way, the video controller can only send commands to control the beam every so often.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yeah, it’s not a limitation of the monitor, but it’s the relevant limitation on the game cabinet.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, there is **always** an effective resolution, which for vector graphics may well be limited by the grain size of the phosphor convolved with the E-beam spot size.